# Key Error 0 in Python after calling a method on linear regression program

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

wondering why I am getting this error. The program itself is just a simple linear regression program based on a small data set. Peeking in at the data it appears to be formatted correctly although when I run it I get a key error 0. Really not sure what could be causing the problem.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    %matplotlib inline

houses = pd.read_csv('/home/devin/Desktop/machineLearning/houses.csv')
houseData = pd.DataFrame(houses)

#x contains the infor on parameters 
x = houseData.drop('price (grands)', axis = 1)
y = houseData['price (grands)']

def cost_func(x, y, weight, bias):
    xLength = len(x)
    total_error = 0.0
    for i in range(xLength):
        total_error += (y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))**2
    return total_error / xLength

def update_weights(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate):
   #initialize derivative values
    weight_deriv = 0
    bias_deriv = 0
    xLength = len(x)
    #calculate partial derivates for our hyperparameters 
    for i in range(xLength):
        # Calculate partial derivatives
        # -2x(y - (mx + b))
        weight_deriv += -2*x[i] * (y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))

        # -2(y - (mx + b))
        bias_deriv += -2*(y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))


    weight -= (weight_deriv / xLength) * learnRate
    bias -= (bias_deriv / xLength) * learnRate

    return weight, bias

def train(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate, epochs):
    cost_history = []

    for i in range(epochs):
        weight,bias = update_weights(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate)

        #Calculate cost for auditing purposes
        cost = cost_func(x,y,weight,bias)
        cost_history.append(cost)

        # Log Progress
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print ("iter: "+str(i) + " cost: "+str(cost) )

    return list(weight, bias, cost_history)


learnRate = 0.0001
initial_bias = 0 # initial y-intercept guess
initial_weight = 0 # initial slope guess
epochs = 10
print ("Running...")    

result = list(train(x, y, initial_weight, initial_bias, learnRate, epochs))
```

> ```
> > Running...
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> ```
>
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          3077             try:
>       -> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          3079             except KeyError:
>
> ```
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 0
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-46-a6b324fbb14b> in <module>()
>       7 print ("Running...")
>       8 
> ----> 9 result = list(train(x, y, initial_weight, initial_bias, learnRate, epochs))
>
> <ipython-input-25-932e205a8590> in train(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate, epochs)
>       4 
>       5     for i in range(epochs):
> ----> 6         weight,bias = update_weights(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate)
>       7 
>       8         #Calculate cost for auditing purposes
>
> <ipython-input-6-59d0fff0ef91> in update_weights(x, y, weight, bias, learnRate)
>      14         # Calculate partial derivatives
>      15         # -2x(y - (mx + b))
> ---> 16         weight_deriv += -2*x[i] * (y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))
>      17 
>      18         # -2(y - (mx + b))
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>    2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>    2687         else:
> -> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
>    2689 
>    2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
>    2693         # get column
>    2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
> -> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
>    2696 
>    2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>    2487         res = cache.get(item)
>    2488         if res is None:
> -> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
>    2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>    2491             cache[item] = res
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
>    4113 
>    4114             if not isna(item):
> -> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>    4116             else:
>    4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> ```
>
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          3079             except KeyError:
>       -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>          3081 
>          3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> ```
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 0
> ```

Comment: What is `type(x)`? I'm guessing it's a `DataFrame`, so when you do `x[0]`you are slicing it by a column, which is named `0` and doesn't exist, thus `KeyError`. You likely either meant to pass a `Series` or `x.values` to your function

Comment: Your object is either empty, or is indexed by something other than natural numbers. Since your data is reading from your hard drive, and we don't have access to your hard drive, this 
is not  a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this is doing, but:

```
[...]
xLength = len(x)
#calculate partial derivates for our hyperparameters 
for i in range(xLength):
   # Calculate partial derivatives
   # -2x(y - (mx + b))
   weight_deriv += -2*x[i] * (y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))
```

Are you sure that `x` and `y` are the same length?

`weight_deriv += -2*x[i] * (y[i] - (weight*x[i] + bias))`

Otherwise you might have an `i` that just does not exist in `y`...

Answer (score 0):

the i in your code is an integer. But x is a data frame and  each column has a different name other than an integer.

I am not sure why you are coding this for yourself, but sklearn library has built in Linear Regression modules that are better optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the `type` of `x` is `DataFrame`; so if you want to index `x` on rows, you could do that using `.iloc`. So, replace every `x[i]` with `x.iloc[i]`.

There is also another small problem. This line

```
return list(weight, bias, cost_history)
```

will throw an Error. you could could solve it by

```
return [weight, bias, cost_history]
```